# Linux:how to 'fork' not exec a new process in a new terminal window?

Tags: linux, process, fork

i am using fedora 15 with posix, and i want to fork my child processes in a new terminal window where i can interact only with the child process while the parent remain int he original terminal. I do not want to exec because that would require me to re arrange all of my code which doesnt seem fesaible at this moment as i have to present my project day after tomorrow.is it possible?how?
i have tried forkpty but it gives me a compilation error.

Comment: Try "gnome-terminal -x command" for gnome-terminal or "xterm -T command" for xterm where command is the command you want executed.  I'm a ubuntu guy so not sure how that translates to fedora

Comment: You will still have to re-assign file descriptors to the new process to the pty of the new terminal. This, and exec, are often used together. I don't see why it would be a problem with re-arranging your code.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to `man screen`. I think it can be what you're looking for..

For example, you can run:

```
screen -dmS SESSION_NAME bash -c "COMMAND"
```

Where SESSION_NAME name is the name of the session, and COMMAND the command that you want to execute. In this way it will start as daemon, detached from your current shell. You're not obliged to do it, but it seems the solution that better fit your question. Remove `-dmS SESSION_NAME` if you want it in foreground.

Then, you can interact with the child with:

```
screen -r SESSION_NAME
```

You can come back to the main shell with:

```
screen -d
```