# How assign a new terminal window to each child process

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec, ipc

I want to fork multiple processes and assign each child process it's own terminal window so that IPC can be demonstrated easily.
Forking goes on fine, and if I run the child processes on the same terminal it runs fine.
However to make each child process have its own terminal window, I do

```
execl("/usr/bin/xterm", "xterm", "-e", "yourprogram", NULL);
```

The program runs in a new window, but its PID is different from that shown by the parent which forks the process. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

edit1 - this is my main function (the parent process). I fork 4 child processes. I want each child process to have its own terminal window. However the child process just exits, and a new process with a different PID continues to run in the new terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

int main()
{

pid_t pid[4]; 
int i = 0;
int status;

//Fork four new processes
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    pid[i] = fork();

    if(pid[i] == 0 && i == 0)
    {
        execl("/usr/bin/xterm", "xterm", "./child1", NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(pid[i] == 0 && i == 1)
    {
        execl("/usr/bin/xterm", "xterm", "./child2", NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(pid[i] == 0 && i == 2)
    {
        execl("/usr/bin/xterm", "xterm", "./child3", NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(pid[i] == 0 && i == 3)
    {
        execl("/usr/bin/xterm", "xterm", "./child4", NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        //Parent process
        printf("The main function has forked a process with pid: %d\n", pid[i]);
    }
}

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    status = waitpid(pid[i], NULL, 0);
    if(status == pid[i])
        printf("%d: Process Terminated Successfully\n", pid[i]);
    else
    {
        perror("waitpid");
        exit(1);
    }
}

return 1;
}
```

edit2 - added ps -u output:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
dell-pc   3024  0.1  0.0  26872  5480 pts/0    Ss   16:54   0:00 bash
dell-pc   3038  0.0  0.0   4200   632 pts/0    S+   16:54   0:00 ./main
dell-pc   3039 22.5  0.1 109240 11116 pts/0    S+   16:54   0:01 xterm ./child1
dell-pc   3040 26.1  0.1 109240 11268 pts/0    R+   16:54   0:02 xterm ./child2
dell-pc   3041 28.7  0.1 109240 11180 pts/0    S+   16:54   0:02 xterm ./child3
dell-pc   3042 27.0  0.1 109240 11288 pts/0    S+   16:54   0:02 xterm ./child4
dell-pc   3044  4.1  0.0   4200   648 pts/24   Ss+  16:55   0:00 child3
dell-pc   3046  3.7  0.0   4200   680 pts/26   Ss+  16:55   0:00 child4
dell-pc   3048  3.8  0.0   4200   792 pts/25   Ss+  16:55   0:00 child2
dell-pc   3050  3.3  0.0   4200   660 pts/14   Ss+  16:55   0:00 child1
dell-pc   3060  2.0  0.0  26816  5412 pts/27   Ss   16:55   0:00 bash
dell-pc   3072  0.0  0.0  22648  2688 pts/27   R+   16:55   0:00 ps -u
```

edit3: added output of main:

```
The main function has forked a process with pid: 3491
The main function has forked a process with pid: 3492
The main function has forked a process with pid: 3493
The main function has forked a process with pid: 3494
3491: Process Terminated Successfully
3492: Process Terminated Successfully
3493: Process Terminated Successfully
3494: Process Terminated Successfully
```

Comment: It could be that you have an answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040334/linuxhow-to-fork-not-exec-a-new-process-in-a-new-terminal-window

Comment: Saw that solution but it doesn't use C code. I need to use C

Comment: I presume you're doing nothing wrong. The terminal runs the command you require with another subprocess.

Comment: But the PID of the child process returned by the parent process and the child process (using getpid()) is different.. That's why i think there is something wrong. Also, the child processes (with PIDs given by the parent process) actually exit after the exec call. Probably, execl forks internally?

Comment: Or probably, calling the xterm creates a fork?

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying. The xterm runs your command "in a `fork()`".

Comment: So there is no need to additionally fork a child process?

Comment: You need it, the xterm need its own process.

Comment: then why are the PIDs different? :/

Comment: Because you have three processes, your main program, it's child running xterm which have his own child running your command.

Comment: I think that the child executes the execl() as just a statement, and then  proceeds to exit, while the execl() spawns a new process with a different PID. Am i correct?

Comment: Try to check your processes list with "ps -u" while your program is running.

Comment: Oh, I see a diffrence with my code, no idea if it is important... Can you use "/usr/bin/xterm" a second time with `execl` instead of "xterm"?

Comment: still getting  different PIDs :(

Comment: @jdarthenay The main motivation for going through all this is because, when different processes output on a single terminal, it gets messy. Can you suggest an alternate solution?

Comment: Easy: output of each subprocess in a given log file, in other xterm you can run `tail -f logfile`.

Comment: I tried your program with my Debian, I got no problem at wall. What is your operating system?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I did a program like yours (naming it stackoverflow), executing `vi` in an xterm, and while it is running I open a third xterm to run `ps -u`. Output is:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
osboxes   1713  0.0  0.2   6588  4756 pts/0    Ss   18:56   0:00 bash
osboxes   1780  0.0  0.2   6508  4484 pts/1    Ss   19:12   0:00 bash
osboxes   1836 88.4  0.0   2020   532 pts/0    R+   19:21   0:29 ./stackoverflow
osboxes   1837  0.1  0.4  12844  8952 pts/0    S+   19:21   0:00 /usr/bin/xterm -e vi stackoverflow.txt
osboxes   1839  0.0  0.1   6072  3536 pts/2    Ss+  19:21   0:00 vi stackoverflow.txt
osboxes   1840  0.0  0.1   4772  2452 pts/1    R+   19:22   0:00 ps -u
```

Output of program is:

```
PID=1836
child PID=1837
```

So the child is still running `xterm`command. It created another child running `vi` (pid 1839).

Comment: But thats not what I want. I want the new terminal to have the same child PID which was forked initially

Comment: @neoprogrammer But this is the case. "child PID=1837" is when I print this number. Compare with fourth entry in `ps -u` results.

Comment: do you first fork a child process? IN my case, the PID of the forked child and the new terminal window are different

Comment: @neoprogrammer are you sure you are not mistaking the xterm process with the program running inside? (fifth line of `ps -u` output). And yes I did `fork()`, without that I would not have `stackoverflow` and `xterm` running together.

Comment: I use getpid() in the program running inside to display the PID of the program running inside. Also, the statement "Process terminated successfully" executes while the program is still executing in the xterm

Comment: @neoprogrammer Check with `xterm` option "-e" like you was originally saying in your question.

Comment: added the ps -u output too also, "-e" option gives the same results

Comment: @neoprogrammer you forget the program output.

Comment: how can the forked processes terminate and give the message "Process terminated successully", while the program running in xterm is still running

Comment: @neoprogrammer, just to be sure, when you enter the `xterm` command without a `&` at end of line, what happens? It should block the terminal from which you launched the command.

Comment: @neoprogrammer Add the output of your program, just to make things clear to everybody reading your question (help others help you).

Comment: the terminal is blocked like you said. The problem is that the PID in the output dont match with that of the xterm

Answer (score 0):

## IPC Demo and sample using terminal windows, under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

Because it's easy under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

This will require simple terminal tools, like `xterm`. This was successfully tested with `lxterm`, `mate-terminal`, `konsole` and `gnome-terminal`. Of course, `tmux` and `screen` must be able too...

**Ok, let's go.** We assume you're already in some terminal window, we will name this *initial console*.

### 1. First opening a display window:

So, from the *initial console*, open *log window*:

```
exec 5> >(xterm -T 'Log window...' -e sh -c "cat /proc/$$/fd/5")
```

or

```
exec 5> >(xterm -e sh -c "printf '\\e];Log window...\\a';cat /proc/$$/fd/5")

exec 5> >(konsole --nofork -e sh -c "cat /proc/$$/fd/5")
exec 5> >(lxterm -T "Log window..." -e sh -c "cat /proc/$$/fd/5")
exec 5> >(mate-terminal -t 'Log window...' -x sh -c "cat /proc/$$/fd/5")
exec 5> >(gnome-terminal --window -x sh -c "printf '\\e];Log window...\\a';cat /proc/$$/fd/5")
```

#### Variant usefull for debugging

```
exec 5> >(xterm -e sh -c "printf '\\e];Log window...\\a';
              tee </proc/$$/fd/5 /dev/tty | sed -u s/.*/now/|date -f -")
```

Will print date and time on each line output.

```
exec 5> >(xterm -e sh -c "printf '\\e];Log window...\\a';
              tee </proc/$$/fd/5 /dev/tty | sed -u s/.*/now/|date -f - ; read foo")
```

Same, but will keep window open after closing from parent, waiting for terminal input (<kbd>Return</kbd>) before closing (or close by window manager).

### 2. Testing, then using this:

Always in *initial console*, hit:

```
echo >&5 This is a test string.
```

This must prompt in *Log window*.

Ok, now:

```
xterm -T 'Input window' -e bash --rcfile <(echo "exec 1>/proc/$$/fd/5") &
```

**Note:** There, ***double-quotes*** will ensure `$$` will expand from *initial window*'s shell level.

So now, you could enter command in *Input window* and read results on *Log window*.

### 3. Closing window

Window will close when file descriptor is closed:

```
exec 5>&-
```

### Full script using 3 window

You may found full script there:

- [ipc_win-demo.sh.txt](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/ipc_win-demo.sh.txt)
- [ipc_win-demo.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/ipc_win-demo.sh)

Comment: Nice! I was searching for `xterm` syntax. But unfortunely the demo won't start on my system (Debian 9)

Comment: @techno Sorry, I've missed `touch $HISTFILE` at line 18. This work fine now! Tested under Debian 9! Thanks! +1 for feedback!

Answer (score 0):

For gnome terminal I used:

```
execl("/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", "gnome-terminal", "-q", "-e", "./my_binary", (char*)0);
```